# It is possible to connect Visual C++ events with Qt slots?

Tags: qt, visual-c++

Is it possible to connect events from Visual C ++ (As if they were Qt signals) with Qt slots?

I would like to connect the Kinect for Windows SDK 2.0 events with Qt slots.

For example, subscribe myHandlerSlot (Qt slot) to the event handler IBodyFrameReader::SubscribeFrameArrived.

My Visual Studio 2013 Solution is structured in two projects:
- Qt project (GUI).
- DLL project containing the Kinect functions. (Only Visual C++/standard C++ includes).

The objetive is to have something like:

```
kinectController->connect(&SubscribeFrameArrived, &MyQtClass::myHandlerSlot);
```

It is possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible. At least in the way you want to use it. However, from your event handler you might call a function (a member function in a Qt class) that will emit a Qt signal. Connecting that signal to a slot will work.